When adding new vertices to a mesh, it messes with the model's weight paints
I'm trying to make a stylized model, with colors set up by using the knife tool and assigning different faces with different materials. I noticed after making the rig though that when I continued trying to make patterns the new vertices would be unassigned.
The only fixes I know are to manually paint every vertex or to massively up the model's poly count and follow the edges with the knife tool, both would be massively tedious, so I'd like to find a fix that simply lets the unassigned vertices follow the weights of the face they're on top of.

Create a copy of the model, do all edit stuff, then use data transfer modifier to copy weights from old model to the new one, using the "Copy from nearest vertex" algorithm: copy thoose settings, targeting the old model, then press the"generate data layers" button, then Apply the modifier (Ctrl A).


This worked! Thank you so much.

You're welcome!
